# Implementation of dropdown menu in HTML

Tags: html, web

I am creating a horizontal navigation bar using HTML and CSS. This work was simple and done with ease. Then I decided to include dropdown menu to each link originally present on the navigation bar.

As a sample assignment, I created a horizontal navigation bar with three links "Dropdown1", "Dropdown2", "Dropdown3" and then added dropdown menus to each of these three links. Each dropdown menu is required to contain only three additional links. (A total of 3x3 = 9 dropdown links. These dropdown links are numbered link01 through link09).

Screenshot of navigation bar links

[image]

The problem is that all the dropdown links get associated with each navigation bar link. I am getting an output similar to

[image]

the same applies when Dropdown1 and Dropdown3 are hovered. Ideally, hover over Dropdown1 must show only Link01, Link02 and Link03. Similarly hover over Dropdown2 must show only Link04, Link05 and Link06 and so on.

The HTML code that I have written is

```
<ul>
<div class="dropdown">
<li>

<a href="#"> Dropdown1</a> 
<div class ="dropdown-content">
<a href="#">Link01</a><!-- actual content of the dropdown will consists of hyperlinks -->
<a href="#">Link02</a>
<a href="#">Link03</a>
</div>

</li>

<li> 
<a href="#"> Dropdown2</a> 
<div class ="dropdown-content">
<a href="#">Link04</a><!-- actual content of the dropdown will consists of hyperlinks -->
<a href="#">Link05</a>
<a href="#">Link06</a>
</div>
</li>
<li> 
<a href="#"> Dropdown3</a> 
<div class ="dropdown-content">
<a href="#">Link07</a><!-- actual content of the dropdown will consists of hyperlinks -->
<a href="#">Link08</a>
<a href="#">Link09</a>
</div>
</li>
</div> <!--closing the dropdown container-->
```

What's the catch?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think it's a better fit for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: Where is the CSS used to generate your current output?

Answer (score 0):

First off, your code is wrong. It's not a valid HTML. Kindly validate your code with W3C Validator before you even think of anything when you wanna ask something.

Secondly, try using the Snippet feature.

Finally, check the CSS part for your solution.

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; font-family: 'Segoe UI'; line-height: 1;}
a {color: #fff; text-decoration: none; display: block;}
.menu {display: inline-block; background-color: #999;}
.menu::after {content: " "; display: block; clear: both;}
.menu > li {float: left; position: relative;}
.menu li a {padding: 15px;}
.menu li:hover > a {background-color: #333;}
.menu ul {display: none; background-color: #999; left: 0; right: 0;}
.menu li:hover ul {display: block; position: absolute;}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="">Dropdown 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Link 01</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 02</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 03</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Dropdown 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Link 01</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 02</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 03</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Dropdown 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Link 01</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 02</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 03</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

If you want to have all the 9 links displayed, you can use something like this:

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none; font-family: 'Segoe UI'; line-height: 1;}
a {color: #fff; text-decoration: none; display: block;}
.menu {display: inline-block; background-color: #999; position: relative;}
.menu::after {content: " "; display: block; clear: both;}
.menu > li {float: left;}
.menu li a {padding: 15px;}
.menu li:hover > a {background-color: #333;}
.menu ul {display: none; background-color: #999; left: 0; right: 0; -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ -moz-column-count: 3; column-count: 3;}
.menu li:hover ul {display: block; position: absolute;}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="">Dropdown 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Link 1-01</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 1-02</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 1-03</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 1-04</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 1-05</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 1-06</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 1-07</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 1-08</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 1-09</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Dropdown 2</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Link 2-01</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 2-02</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 2-03</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 2-04</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 2-05</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 2-06</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 2-07</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 2-08</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 2-09</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="">Dropdown 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Link 3-01</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 3-02</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 3-03</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 3-04</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 3-05</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 3-06</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 3-07</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 3-08</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 3-09</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I have used CSS3 Columns for the above.